# Let $c$, $d$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}^+$ be positive integers which are coprime. Show that $cd \mid a$, for an integer $a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I wrote a proof for this, not sure if it's correct though.

Let $c$, $d$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}^+$ be positive integers which are coprime. Show that $cd \mid a$, for an integer $a$.

Assume $cd \mid a$

By the assumption, $a$ is some multiple of $cd$

So $a$ can be written as $cda$

Hence $cd \mid a$.

I'm not sure if this is correct because the question mentions that $c$ and $d$ are coprime. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well you've assumed that $cd \mid a$ and then concluded that $cd \mid a$. Can you see perhaps the problem with this?

Comment: Moreover, what is $a$ precisely meant to be here? As if you want to show that some such $a$ exists simply take $a=cd$.

Comment: $a$ is any integer

Comment: Extending Cryptokyo's comment, it is called circular reasoning:  **To prove**: $(3 \times 4) | (11)$ : Assume $(3 \times 4) | (11)$.  Then, there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $(11) = (3\times 4) \times k$.

Comment: Okay well this question doesn't seem to make much sense in its current state as if I took $c=2$ and $d=3$ then $cd$ does not divide 5. So it certainly cannot hold for every integer. Perhaps maybe editing your post to make it clearer what you're asking would be helpful here.

Comment: @Tortar the second line of the question is likely the exact wording of the problem. In which case, it wants OP to show that each $c,d\in\Bbb N$ has an integer their product divides into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a proof like this, you have to quantify what $a$ is, in terms of $c$ and $d$. In other words, you want to find an $a(c,d)\in\Bbb N$ such that for each $c,d\in \Bbb N$, it follows that $cd|a(c,d)$. Can you find this?

Extra Hint: Use the property that $$\{c|a \cap d|a\}\implies cd|a$$

Answer (score 2):

This question seems like it has to be missing something, I would double check to make sure the problem is correctly formulated. If you let $c,d$ be any integers then $cd \mid cd$ so set $a=cd$ and you're done.